# Passing in a file path to FileReader

Tags: file, path, filereader

Using Netbeans, I am trying to pack some text file resources that are read by a FileReader into a JAR file, but since the text files aren't located in the resources folder, the JAR cannot find them. How can I tell the filereader where to look for the files? (Such as "/src/resources/maps/level1.txt" in my case.)

Currently, the text files are stored in the project folder and can be read from there using "filename.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. this sounds like two questions. First, resources get packed into a JAR file and can't be read directly as files (yes, you can execute classes on "exploded" directory mode but your code shouldnt depend on this).  Once you have generated a JAR file containing your classes and the resources, you can access the resource using an InputStreamReader, not a FileReader

```
new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/maps/level1.txt"));
```

The reason that getResourceAsStream() is on the Class object, is that sometimes resources are placed in same package as a class.  Using..

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("level1.txt")
```

without a / slash at the front of the path, this would try to locate this in the same package as "this" object.

When resources are in the root package, or have their own directory structure, /maps/ for example. You can call this.getClass() on any class (in the same classloader) to find the resource.